# Mule SFDC Connector without user interaction using sfdc:config-with-oauth

Tags: rest-api, salesforce1-app, oauth2

I am trying to access Salesforce through my Mule flows using "sfdc:config-with-oauth". Is there any way I can achieve this without redirecting the user to a Login page? I know there is a SSO login dance which I have to do manually, but was hoping it was simpler than that. I found this documentation http://mulesoft.github.io/salesforce-connector/mule/sfdc-config-with-oauth.html. It shows "sfdc:authorize/", but that is not accurate. sfdc:authorize has DISPLAY as a required attribute. What is the meaning of "IMMEDIATE" attribute? Is it possible, somehow, to give Username/Password along with Consumer Key/Secret to "sfdc:config-with-oauth"?

My Mule flow already has User credentials.

I am using Mule Studio 3.5.0

Comment: Also being  discussed at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23554357/mule-sfdc-connector-without-user-interaction-using-sfdcconfig-with-oauth